# Has it been revealed what Jugo and Sugeitsu found in the lair?

Tags: naruto

I've been following quite closely but might have missed this. What is it that Jugo and Sugeitsu found in Oro's lair? See: http://www.mangareader.net/naruto/574/6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it was revealed in the manga. The scroll is a Jutsu Scroll for [`Shiki Fuujin: Kai`](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Demon_Consuming_Seal%3a_Release), the method to unseal the Dead Reaper Seal.

It was thanks to this that Orochimaru was able to revive the 4 previous Kages, whose souls were originally sealed within the Death God.